# Ruby understanding threads on a deeper level

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I've been researching this topic for weeks at this point, and I'm starting to think I'm stupid, because I just can't understand. I do not grasp the concept. At all. I've tried, and tried again, but this just isn't being absorbed. So hopefully this won't somehow be considered a low quality question. I'm asking because despite all the research I've done, and all the practice code I've written, I simply don't get it, and I can't figure it out. So I'll get to the point.

I have been working a lot with networking and Ruby, and some of my scripts involve a high number of connections. As such, it slows done the performance of the script drastically. Obviously if I'm trying to connect to 1000 hosts with a timeout of 1 second, it'll take awhile. Unless of course, I multi-thread my application, right? Concurrency would solve that problem, and it did! That's when I discovered race conditions. This is what I've been researching for weeks now. I can speed up my program with concurrency, but now, the results are corrupted. Research has often led to to using a mutex, which as far as I understand makes it so that no threads will access any resource at the same time. Which would solve the race conditions issue, because obviously if no threads are both trying to access the same resource, then the results would not be corrupted. However, what I find completely ridiculous is that implementing a mutex makes the application behave as though I had never bothered multithreading the application in the first place. What is the point of that?

So that's my question, what good is creating a multithreaded application, and then adding a mutex, which **by definition** makes it so that only one thread can execute code at a time? Sounds completely contradictory to me. I really hope this isn't considered a bad or useless question, or showing lack of research. I sincerely have been researching and struggling to understand how to correctly multithread my code, without experiencing race-conditions, for weeks, and I just don't get it. It's a programming related question, and I do not believe I'm the only one who has these kinds of questions.

I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Mutexes don't protect _every_ resource from every thread, they only protect the resources that you tell them to protect! If you protect _every_ resouce with a mutex, then yeah your multithreaded code is going to run no faster than serialized code. They key is to protect _as few resources as possible_ and to protect them very briefly e.g. lock, write output, unlock. That lets the threads work as independently as possible.

Comment: It's my understanding that locking, etc, can abstract and confuse even more, and as an **extreme** novice at this sort of thing I feel that I'd be throwing myself into the fire. Isn't there a simpler way to speed up your code without race conditions, e.g. using a queue or actors, or is using a mutex the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what good is creating a multithreaded application, and then adding a
>   mutex, which by definition makes it so that only one thread can
>   execute code at a time?

Network connections involve a lot of waiting around in terms of computer processing speeds.  The idea is that most of the time those connections will happen at different times, so there won't be a race condition where two threads simultaneously try to modify some data your program uses.  However, there is a small chance that the results returned by two connections could occur at the exact same time, and then two threads could try to access some data in your program at the exact same time.  To protect against that, you can use mutex's, locks, etc.  But most of the time there won't be ANY waiting for a lock to unlock--it will already be unlocked.

> Isn't there a simpler way to speed up your code without race
>   conditions, e.g. using a queue

Queue's are a great way to organize pools of worker threads.  You can start a bunch of threads that read from a *task* Queue.  Because the task Queue is initially empty, all the threads will hang waiting for something to be put in the Queue.  Then you dump a bunch of tasks, e.g. urls, into the task Queue, and each thread retrieves one of the urls from the task Queue, establishes a connection, then dumps the results into a *results* Queue--from which your program reads the results at its leisure.

The worker threads retrieve tasks from the task Queue inside an infinite loop, so as soon as they dump a result in the results Queue, they go back up to the top of the loop and retrieve another task from the task Queue.  Inside the loop, you can write something like:

```
break if url == "NO_MORE_TASKS"
```

After you dump all the tasks into the task Queue, you then dump a bunch of strings into the task Queue that say, "NO_MORE_TASKS"--one for each worker thread.

There will be an optimal number of worker threads, which you can discover by trying different numbers: 5, 10, 20, 40, 100, and timing your program.

Comment: This was an extremely helpful and useful answer. This clarified quite a few things for me and helped me decide which direction I want to go in to solve this. Thanks for taking the time to respond so thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was phrased very general--as a conceptual question--so I'll phrase my answer in the same way.

In order to use a bunch of threads correctly to execute a bunch of similar tasks you must arrange your code in such a way that the threads don't ever interact with the same resource (Generally).

Think of how you would manage a group of people working on a task of sorting papers.  If you just told them all to sort that huge pile of papers  you'd end up with a huge mess!  But if you start out with a meeting, hand each person a set of papers and charge them with sorting their set, then when each is finished have them give their sorted papers to someone who can easily combine two stacks of sorted papers, the work can be threaded smoothly.

The trick is that before you start you organize the work to be done by each thread and when you are done you combine the results, but while you are working each worker must be in a completely walled-off area doing his work.

Combining them at the end can be a bit of trouble, that's the part where the mutex would come in handy (Since the last part has to be accessed by all the different threads), but the "Long" individual parts are finished by then so single-threading the combining operation shouldn't cost much time.

Answer (score 1):

Moved from comments since it was getting long.

Mutexes don't protect every resource from every thread, they only protect the resources that you tell them to protect! If you protect every resource with a mutex, then yeah your multithreaded code is going to run no faster than serialized code. They key is to protect as few resources as possible and to protect them very briefly e.g. lock, write output, unlock. That lets the threads work as independently as possible.

Multithreaded data structures (e.g. queues) still use mutexes internally to avoid race conditions - they're only "simpler" from a coding standpoint since they abstract out the locking/unlocking. They won't be any more performant. That being said, such structures can be more semantic and safer to use than mutexes, so they should be preferred if they satisfy your needs.

Mutexes are the fundamental building blocks of thread-safe code - only use them if your requirements are so simple that you don't need anything fancy, or so complex that you need to engineer something novel.

A great use-case for mutexes is a shared global variable.

```
require 'thread'
stdout_mutex = Mutex.new

a = Thread.new {
  # run some code that could take a while

  stdout_mutex.synchronize {
    $stdout.puts "Thread A done!"
  }
}

b = Thread.new {
  # run some code that could take while

  stdout_mutex.synchronize {
    $stdout.puts "Thread B done!"
  }
}
```